# How to get all the specific key value from multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, key, multidimensional-array

How can I get the all the 'name' and 'city' value back in an array from the following multidimensional array?

```
$myarray=Array(Array('name' => 'A','id' => '1', 'phone' => '416-23-55',
Base => Array ('city'  => 'toronto'),'EBase' => Array('city' => 'North York'),
'Qty' => '1'),  (Array('name' =>'B','id' => '1','phone' => '416-53-66','Base' => 
Array  ('city' => 'qing'), 'EBase' => Array('city' => 'chong'),'Qty' => '2')));
```

I expect the returned value be

```
$namearray=Array('A','B');
$basecityarray=Array('toronto','qing');
$Ebasecityarray=Array('North York','chong');
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are right.  I updated the expected result. Could you help?

Comment: just use `foreach` or `array_map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely try something like this:

```
$shop = array( array( 'Title' => "rose", 
                  'Price' => 1.25,
                  'Number' => 15 
                ),
           array( 'Title' => "daisy", 
                  'Price' => 0.75,
                  'Number' => 25,
                ),
           array( 'Title' => "orchid", 
                  'Price' => 1.15,
                  'Number' => 7 
                )
         );
```

You can access the first row as

```
echo $shop[0][0]." costs ".$shop[0][1]." and you get ".$shop[0][2]."<br />";
```

or `$shop[0]->Title` will return to you `rose`.